# keep x rows and delete all from csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to be able to specify how many rows I want to keep and delete the rest, also preserving the header.

I found some code which let's you delete the first 5 rows but how can I make it do what I want?

```
with open ('myfile.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
    outfile.writelines(data_in[1])
    outfile.writelines(data_in[5:])
```

For example if I have this CSV

```
6.5, 5.4, 0, 000
6.5, 5.4, 1, 610
1.2, 4.0, 0, 530
3.2, 5.4, 1, 330
4.2, 3.0, 0, 320
5.5, 2.3, 1, 780
1.3, 4.4, 0, 520
5.3, 1.0, 0, 420
```

I just want to specify a number to my script... let's say (2) and it will KEEP 2 rows and remove all others

output would become:

```
6.5, 5.4, 0, 000
6.5, 5.4, 1, 610
```

Can i also make it save it with a different name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you first read your original CSV-file into variable `data_in` with commands

```
with open('my_original_file.csv') as inp:
     data_in = inp.readlines()
```

you may continue:

```
n = int(input("How many rows after header you want to write: "))

with open('myfile.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.writelines(data_in[:n+1])
```

This will write

- the header row —  `data_in[0]`, and
- subsequent n rows — `data_in[1]` to `data_in[n]`

Comment: @Saffik, I used this name from your code, supposing, that you know what it means.

Comment: Although the code snippet mentioned this "data_in" but I didnt understand it. I get ERROR: `NameError: name 'data_in' is not defined`

Comment: @Saffik, I inserted 2 lines of code in the beginning of my answer, showing you, how to fill the variable `data_in`.

Answer (score 1):

With `pandas` it is very easy to do, you can use `head`:

```
#reading the csv file (remove header=None if you have column names)
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv',header=None)

#selecting only first 2 rows
df = df.head(2)

#saving the csv file (remove header= None if you have column names)
df.to_csv('output.csv',index=False, header=False)
```

Or simply:

```
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv',header=None)
df.head(2).to_csv('output.csv',index=False, header=False)
```

**Output**:

```
6.5,5.4,0,0
6.5,5.4,1,610
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the first `n` lines and remove everything else:

```
with open(filename, 'r+') as f:
    for i in range(n):
        f.readline() # read each line
    f.truncate(f.tell()) # terminate the file here
```